# How do I make strace "decode" AF_NETLINK communication as with ioctl?

Tags: linux-kernel, strace

`strace` usually "deciphers" `ioctl` calls, showing what they mean, even resolving network interface names and so on.

But the same operation performed using AF_NETLINK stays opaque in `strace`. How can I teach `strace` to look into `AF_NETLINK` things? Are there patches or forks with this feature?

```
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"0\0\0\0\32\0\1\0\323K\255S\0\0\0\0\n\200\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\24\0\1\0"..., 48}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 48
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\224\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\323K\255S\3674\0\0\n\200\200\0\0\2\0\7\0\0\0\0\10\0\17\0"..., 16384}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 148
```

Example of "cooked" strace output with `ioctl`

```
ioctl(4, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="veth0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_ALLMULTI}) = 0
```

#### Background on AF_NETLINK

*excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink)*

> The `AF_NETLINK` family offers multiple protocol subsets. Each interfaces to a different kernel component and has a different messaging subset. The following protocol is referenced in the field below:
>
> ```
>   int socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM or SOCK_RAW, protocol)
> ```
>
> Lacking a standard, `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_RAW` are not guaranteed to be implemented in a given Linux (or other OS) release. Some sources state that both options are legitimate, and the reference below from Red Hat states that `SOCK_RAW` is always the parameter, however iproute2 uses both interchangeably.

Comment: @Braiam, 1. What's wrong with "netlink" tag?; 2. Why "linux" tag got removed? Isn't the question Linux-specific?

Comment: I can see all (most) the communication (with `strace -s 100000`). The question is about decoding it. strace seem to have a pack of helpers that know about `ioctl`s and looks up process memory for relevant things, but not for those special sockets. It is the question of interpreting the information, not extracting.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of the `ioctl` calls you are referring to? Along with an `ioctl` call that works properly on a non-AF_NETLINK socket? I'm not grasping what the relevance of the `sendmsg` and `recvmsg` lines are.

Comment: Are you trying to see the send/recvmsg payload?

Comment: I see the payload already (look at the `"\224\0\0\0\30` above for example). I want strace to decode it, like with ioctl and see command names and parameters etc.

Comment: @Vi. strace can't do that. The contents of the payload are only relevant to the application sending and receiving the payload. It could be anything. I could invent my own protocol, and have 2 applications exchange data through it.

Comment: @Patrick, But I expect the kernel netlink interface used by, for example, iproute2 to be standardized. Why I can directly see in strace that program adds a route to routing table with SIOCADDRT (and strace even writes friendly name of network interface), but not when the same action performed with NETLINK instead of ioctl?

Comment: Strace could theoretically have code added to do this, but you'd also need to add code to identify which file descriptors are netlink sockets and which netlink_family they are. Using `socket` isn't the only way to create a file descriptor; it can be created by `dup`, `dup2`, or inherited  after a `fork` or `clone` or `exec`. By contrast, everything strace needs to know in order to decode an ioctl is passed in the call to ioctl.

Comment: @Vi. For netlink debugging, you can also set up a monitor device (`ip link add nlmon0 type nlmon && ip link set nlmon0 up`) and capture using tcpdump/wireshark. Wireshark supports netlink and there have also been some further improvements in the master branch (2.3.x).